# Iterate through ArrayList for specific key-value in Angular 5

Tags: json, angular, typescript, arraylist

How do I iterate through my arrayList and return keys of of specific values? My data is in a Json format as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Albany",
        "manufacture": "Albany Superior Low Gi Sliced Brown Seed Bread 700g",
        "price": 15.49,
        "category": "Food",
        "type": "Breads",
        "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA..."
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Blue Ribbon",
        "manufacture": "Blue Ribbon Brown Plus Low Gi Bread 700g",
        "price": 13.99,
        "category": "Food",
        "type": "Breads",
        "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA..."
    },
    {...},
    {...},
    ...
]
```

I was able to return the following data:

[image]

I have written the following codes to fetch a single product for *type-Milk*:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-milk-cream',
  templateUrl: './milk-cream.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./milk-cream.component.css']
})
export class MilkCreamComponent implements OnInit {

  allProducts: Array<Product> = [];
  quantity: number = 1;
  resultArray:any;

  constructor( private prod: ProductService) { }

  CallbackFunctionToFindTypeById(prod) {
    return prod.type === 'Milk';
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.allProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('product-data') );
    //console.log( JSON.stringify( this.allProducts ) );

    var productMilk = this.allProducts.find(this.CallbackFunctionToFindTypeById);
    console.log( productMilk );
  }
}

interface Product {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  manufacture: string;
  price: number;
  category: string;
  type: string;
  image: string;
}
```

I then edited CallbackFunctionToFindTypeById method, for it to loop and return an arrayList with products of Milk type; the problem is I could not call that method in ngOnInit (**not sure that it works too**):

```
CallbackFunctionToFindTypeById(prod) {

    for (var i=0; i < this.allProducts.length; i++){
      if ( prod.type === 'Milk' ){
        this.allProducts[i];
      }
    }
    return this.allProducts;
  }
```

I am new in Angular 5 and TypeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `filter` which returns all the items in the array that macthes the predicate

```
var productMilk = this.allProducts.filter(item => item.type === 'Milk');
```

Comment: Ok. Happy to help you